# What are the record type struct and classes different use cases?

Tags: c#-record-type, c#-10.0

Why are the `struct` and `class` variant of a record type different. And what would be use cases for both?

Comment: Maybe it would be better phrased as "how" rather than "why", because surely the answer to "Why" is that if they weren't different, there wouldn't be a need for both.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever with why I more meant a what are the different use cases, because I know the how

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as `why are there value and reference types`? This isn't a case of variants of a record type, the record functionality is applied to value (struct) or reference (class) types. You have a class with `record` semantics or a struct with `record` semantics.

Comment: @RoyBerris Are you asking when you should use `record` and where you should use `record struct`? Do I get your question correctly?